# what is the max number of nodes if a given graph is 5 regular

Tags: graph-theory

I want to find the maximum no. of nodes in any 5 regular graph.
I know that the minimum number of nodes will be 6.
New in the area of graph theory

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum. Let $G_1,\ldots,G_n$ be disjoint copies of $K_6$; the union of these $n$ graphs is $5$-regular and has $6n$ nodes. If you want the graph to be connected, make the following modification. Let For $k=1,\ldots,n-1$ let $u_k$ and $v_k$ be distinct nodes of $G_k$, and for $k=2,\ldots,n$ let $x_k$ and $y_k$ be distinct nodes of $G_k$. Further, make sure that if $2\le k\le n-1$, the four nodes $x_k,y_k,u_k$, and $v_k$ are all distinct.

Now delete all of the edges $u_kv_k$ and $x_ky_k$ and replace them with edges $u_kx_{k+1}$ and $v_ky_{k+1}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$; each vertex still has degree $5$, and the graph is now connected. (I suggest drawing an example with $n=2$ and perhaps also with $n=3$.)

Comment: Consider a network in which person A has n friends, the n friends of person A each have

n friends, and those n friends each have n friends. There are no other people in this

network other than those mentioned. Assume that people cannot be their own friends.

(i) What is the largest number of people who could possibly be in such a network?

Draw the structure of this network assuming n = 5.

(ii) What is the smallest number? Again draw the structure of the network assuming

n = 5.
This question came in my exams Can someone help me with this and the approach I should use to solve this

Comment: @Abhishek: It would be better to ask this as a separate question.